# How could I access a script in 'A' prefab object from 'B' prefab object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a multiplayer game using unity network. I have created two prefab object, one is 'player' prefab object and another is 'bullet' prefab object. health script attached with 'player' prefab and similarly bullet script attached with 'bullet' prefab. But I'm facing a problem when I trying to access a public method in 'player' prefab from 'bullet' prefab.

please help me how do I solve it.

//::::::Health Script:::::

```
using UnityEngine;

public class health : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth = maxHealth;
    public void takeDamage(int amount)
    {
        currentHealth -= amount;

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            currentHealth = 0;
            Debug.Log("player death");
        }
    }
}
```

//:::::Bullet Script:::::

```
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
         if(collision.collider.tag == "Player")
         {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<health>().takeDamage(10);

            // OR

            GameObject Em = collision.gameObject;
            health healths = Em.GetComponent<health>();

            if (healths != null)
            {
                healths.takeDamage(10);
            }

            // OR

            GameObject clone = collision.collider.gameObject;
            health myComponent = clone.GetComponent<health>();
            myComponent.takeDamage(10);
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqm2p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32bFt.png)

Comment: What's the error? Please post what the issue is.

Comment: Those are all exactly the same. If you *really* wanted to you could do `collision.collider.transform.gameObject`, but why. The only functional difference between them is the null check, which you could replace with a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators), `?.`

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: hi  Draco18s, now I'm using this code. 
collision.collider.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<health>().takeDamage(10);
but still getting the same error
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: First of all if it is a GameObject taking part in a Collision both objects are instances in a Scene .. so please don't call them `prefab` .. this only is confusing. Second, can you please post the entire error message and mark in which line exactly the exception is thrown?

Comment: hi @derHugo, error is "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
bullet.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collision) (at Assets/Scripts/bullet.cs:27)".


now I'm using this code.
collision.collider.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<health>().takeDamage(10);
or
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<health>().takeDamage(10);
both scenario I've got the same error.

Comment: Maybe you should use breakpoints and see where exactly a reference is not set ..